# Firefox 8 issue with drag events

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, drag-and-drop

## Additional info edit

- Ok, it works with **Firefox 9.0.1**.
- I feel that Firefox 8 is running `dragEnter` and `dragLeave` in same time.
- The `dropZoneElement` is a `<a>` element.
- Screenshot :

[image]

---

## Context

The following code works with Chrome 16 ( in a logical and expected way) and it completely bug with Firefox 8. With Firefox, when I mouseover the `dropZoneElement`, my style sometimes appears, sometimes it doesn't appear, without any logic. I move the mouse to 1px, it appears, or vice versa.

## Question

What is going on with Firefox?

## Code

**[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):**

```
dropZoneElement.addEventListener('dragenter', function(e) {
  if (e.dataTransfer.types == 'Files' || e.dataTransfer.types[2] == 'Files') {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $this.addClass('gmail-like');
  }
}, false);

dropZoneElement.addEventListener('dragleave', function(e) {
  if (e.dataTransfer.types == 'Files' || e.dataTransfer.types[2] == 'Files') {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $this.removeClass('gmail-like');
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: `dragenter` should be `dragBegin`

Comment: `dragBegin` doesn't work with Chrome and Firefox.